# JqueryUI Slider let the change event handler wait for another change event

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I set up my jqueryUI slider with two handles. Its' change event handler looks like that:

```
change: function(event, ui){
    $("#priceFilterForm").submit();
},
```

It fires the form as soon as one handle was moved.

---

I want the change event handler to behave like that:

- If a change event is fired wait for 3 seconds
- If another change event is fired reset the 3 second timer
- If there is no other change event within 3 seconds submit the form

Can you please hint me a technique on how to achieve that behavior.

---

Solution thank's to Garry:

```
var timer = $.timer(function(){
   $("#priceFilterForm").submit();
});

// slider options:

slide: function(event, ui){
    timer.pause();
    // ...
},
change: function(event, ui){
    timer.stop();  // Not sure if stop is needed here..
    timer.set({ time : 1500, autostart : true });
}
```

+ Don't forget to include the timer plugin into your javascript

Comment: You could look into the jQuery hoverIntent plugin, maybe try to modify it for `.change` instead of `.hover`, or just get an idea of how it works: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/hoverIntent the idea is exactly the same as yours except with a different input listener.

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer = $.timer(function() {
            alert('This message was sent by a timer.');
    });

    timer.set({ time : 5000, autostart : true });

    timer.set(options);
    timer.play(reset);  // Boolean. Defaults to false.
    timer.pause();
    timer.stop();  // Pause and resets
    timer.toggle(reset);  // Boolean. Defaults to false.
    timer.once(time);  // Number. Defaults to 0.
    timer.isActive  // Returns true if timer is running
    timer.remaining // Remaining time when paused
```

Demo

http://jchavannes.com/jquery-timer/demo

Download

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-timer/downloads/detail?name=jquery-timer.zip
View Source

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-timer/source/browse/